# iOS SDK grab elements in xml code

Tags: ios, xml, parsing

I've search the web for a solution. I am developing an application that fetches some xml content from a webserver. I can run the xml code in a log and every thing is returned OK. So that is working.

My problem is when it is time to parse the xml. My xml code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Content>

<Name>
John Doe
</Name>

<Adress>
Road 123
</Adress>

</Content>
```

How can grab the Name and the adress element and put the string "John Doe" and "Road 123" inside a string.

I hope someone can help me because i am really confused :s

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of many many many questions...

Try googling "XML Parsing iOS" - in fact please try googling your problem before posting any question on Stack Overflow.

Anyway, I'll give you a clue - have a look at [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003773)